# If $|x-x_0|<\frac {\varepsilon}{2}$ and $|y-y_0|<\frac {\varepsilon}{2}$ then $|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)|<\varepsilon$ and $|(x-y)-(x_0-y_0)|<\varepsilon$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

This is a problem from Spivak's Calculus 4th ed., Chapter 1

> If $|x-x_0|<\frac {\varepsilon}{2}$ and $|y-y_0|<\frac {\varepsilon}{2}$ then $|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)|<\varepsilon$ and $|(x-y)-(x_0-y_0)|<\varepsilon$

Here is my proof:

If $|x-x_0|<\frac {\varepsilon}{2}$ and $|y-y_0|<\frac {\varepsilon}{2}$ then $|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|<\varepsilon$ (I've proved that if $a<c$ and $b<d$ then $a+b<c+d$ in a previous exercise so I used that to come to this conclusion).

$|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|\geq|x-x_0+y-y_0|=|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)|$ (I've proved in a previous exercise that $|x|+|y|\geq|x+y|$ in a previous exercise so I used that to come to this conclusion.

$\therefore$ Since $|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)|\leq|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)|<\varepsilon$ it follows that $|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)|<\varepsilon$.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: $|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)|\color{red}=|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)|$

Comment: There is no question?

Comment: I think the question is, "Is my proof correct?"

Comment: The question is, indeed, "Is my proof correct?" Sorry for the confusion I just edited this.

Answer (score 4):

It is correct, but you could have written it as follows :

Suppose $|x-x_0|<\varepsilon /2$ and $|y-y_0|<\varepsilon /2$.

Now
$$\begin{align}
|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)| &= |(x-x_0)+(y-y_0)| \\
&\leq |x-x_0|+|y-y_0| &  (\textrm{by triangle inequality}) \\
&< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} & (\textrm{by assumption}) \\
&= \varepsilon .
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct except the last sentence. You can say:
The result is clear since
$$
|(x+y)-(x_0+y_0)| \le |x-x_0|+|y-y_0|< \epsilon.
$$